# Why is the WebApplicationFactory not resetting between tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, fixtures

I have two tests of an ASP.NET core webapp within a single test class. The class uses an `IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>`.

The first test is a happy path test: when a message arrives on a Kafka topic, some file appears in a particular output directory.

The second test is to verify that if something goes wrong with outputting said file, the webapp should then be in an unhealthy status.

For brevity, I'm omitting the code that publishes to Kafka and that generates the output folder the application saves files to - neither of these are relevant.

```
[CollectionDefinition("e2e", DisableParallelization = true)]
[Trait("Category", "IntegrationTest")]
public class EndToEndTest : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>, IClassFixture<KafkaFixture>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public EndToEndTest(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        KafkaUtils.Publish(SomeMessage()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenXReceived_ThenFileIsOutput()
    {
        var options = OutputFolder();
        Directory.CreateDirectory(options.Path);

        RunService(services => services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(options))).CreateClient();
        
        Thread.Sleep(10_000);

        var outputDirectory = Directory.GetFiles(options.Path);
        Assert.Single(outputDirectory);
        var file = outputDirectory.Single();
        Assert.NotEmpty(File.ReadAllLinesAsync(file).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

        Directory.Delete(options.Path, true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenFileTransferFails_ThenAppShouldBeUnhealthy()
    {
        var options = OutputFolder();
        // only try once, so we don't have to wait
        var retry = new RetryPolicyConfiguration {OnErrorRetryCount = 1};

        var factory = RunService(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(options));
            services.AddSingleton(Options.Create(retry));
            services.RemoveAll<IFileWriter>();
            services.AddScoped<IFileWriter, ThrowingFileWriter>();
        });

        var client = factory.CreateClient();
        Thread.Sleep(10_000);

        Assert.False(Directory.Exists(options.Path));

        var response = client.GetAsync("/health/ready").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var health = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HealthCheckResult>(body);
        Assert.NotEqual(HealthStatus.Healthy, health.Status);
    }

    protected WebApplicationFactory<Startup> RunService(Action<IServiceCollection> serviceConfig)
    {
        return _factory
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder => builder
                .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    serviceConfig(services);
                    services.AddSubscribeBus(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile(ConfigMapFileProvider.FromRelativePath("config"),
                            "appsettings.e2e.json", true, true)
                        .Build());
                }));
    }
}

public class ThrowingFileWriter : IFileWriter
{
    public void Write(string fileName, envelope envelope)
    {
        throw new Exception("foo");
    }

    public void Delete(string fileName)
    {
    }
}
```

If I run `WhenFileTransferFails_ThenAppShouldBeUnhealthy()` (*unhealthyTest* from here on, for brevity) on its own, then the test passes. But if I run the entire test class, then `WhenXReceived_ThenFileIsOutput()` (*healthyTest*, for brevity) runs before it, and for some reason *unhealthyTest* seems to use the service context that was created for *healthyTest*.

I've tried my best to work out what's going on, but it doesn't make sense to me. When I debug through it, the order of events is roughly as follows:

1. *healthyTest* starts
2. Startup invoked for *healthytest*
3. Constructor of service that uses `IFileWriter` is invoked with real instance of service
4. *healthyTest* completes
5. *unhealthyTest* starts
6. Constructor of service that uses `IFileWriter` is invoked with real instance of service (???)
7. Startup invoked for *unhealthyTest*
8. `serviceConfig` action invoked for *unhealthyTest*: all implementations of `IFileWriter` replaced with `ThrowingFileWriter` - but this is too late, it's already been constructed with the real instance in step 6

Consequently, the real service is used instead of the throwing service, and the exception handler that sets the app status to Unhealthy is never invoked.

Originally this was all running asynchronously, but I thought that perhaps the async nature of the tests meant that the two were conflicting with the webapp created by the factory - hence all the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

What am I doing wrong in my setup of the webapp for the test?

Note: it's unfortunately *absolutely not an option* to move these tests into their own test classes.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I'd suggest implementing `IAsyncLifetime` instead of trying to do async setup in your constructor. I'd also make your tests async (it's supported out of the box in xunit), rather than using `GetAwaiter()`.

Comment: @MartinCostello as I said, this was all originally async - I've just been trying to track down the problem, and in doing so tried to make it all synchronous via `GetAwaiter()`. Once I've established what the problem is, I'll likely revert that change

Comment: I can confirm this.  Tests run fine if you stick the WebApplicationFactory on a static property and reuse it.  But that only works if your tests can share a service config.